# How to make my popen read-only stream non-buffered?

Tags: c++, shell, process, io

As far as I can tell, the advised method of calling a shell command and reading its output is via `popen` (e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/478960/1398282)). However, the man page for `popen(3)` says:

```
Note that output popen() streams are block buffered by default.
```

How do I make my read-only pipe non-buffered?

For example:

```
FILE* ro_pipe = popen("echo hello", "r");
```

won't fill out the 4KB output buffer, but I'd want to have the output data ready to read as soon as it is written to the stdout of the shell command.